# Is there a Python function for this piece of code?

Tags: python, graph

I created a graph by putting nodes in a list. Node is a class with attributes 'parent', 'daughters', and 'edge'. I want to check if a symbol is in the edges of any of the daughter-nodes of a current node, and if so, to change the current node to that node. If not, then I create a new node with that edge, and change the current node to it.

I do this like this:

```
match = False
for daughter in currentNode.daughters:
    if daughter.edge == currentSymbol:
        match = True
        currentNode = daughter
if match == False:
    trie.append(node(currentNode, [], currentSymbol)
    currentNode = trie[-1]
```

The use of 'match' seems inelegant to me. Is there a better syntax for checking if the edge exists among the daughters, and if so, updating the current node to that daughter, and if not, creating that node?

Comment: `for/else`, maybe: http://python-notes.curiousefficiency.org/en/latest/python_concepts/break_else.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`for/else`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops) here:

```
for daughter in currentNode.daughters:
    if daughter.edge == currentSymbol:
        currentNode = daughter
        break
else:
    trie.append(node(currentNode, [], currentSymbol)
    currentNode = trie[-1]
```

The `else` case will be executed if the `for` loop exited normally, i.e. without `break`

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `for...else` syntax here:

```
for daughter in currentNode.daughters:
    if daughter.edge == currentSymbol:
        currentNode = daughter
        break
else:
    trie.append(node(currentNode, [], currentSymbol)
    currentNode = trie[-1]
```

The `else` part is executed, only if the for loop completed normally without ever breaking. So in your case, if you find a match, you break from the loop (aborting it), and the `else` is skipped. And if you don’t find a match, you never break from the loop, and the `else` is executed.